# Move magento title xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i move breadcrumbs, but now i need that Title Page show below, actually html show

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
<div class="col-main">
    <div class="my-account">
        <div class="page-title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
<div class="page-title"></div>
<div class="col-main">
    <div class="my-account"></div>
</div>
```

How can i do this, i suposse is necessary modify xml file but i not find the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I choose create new custom block in page.xml

```
<block type="core/template" name="my_top_title" as="my_top_title" template="page/html/toptitle.phtml"/>
```

In 2columns-left.phtml,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_top_title') ?>
```

In toptitle.phtml

```
<?php $title=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?>
<div class="my-title">
    <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
</div>
```

Works fine.

Comment: Case for your own template